# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) could not open file "3aG5OjRRd1.csv" for reading: Permission denied

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

Hi i am working on a finance project that requires csv files to be imported so that the data can be analyzed easily, but when i run the importing script file i end up with:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) could not open file "3aG5OjRRd1.csv" for reading: Permission denied`

I am using python, psycopg2, sqlalchemy to do the importation: below is my script file:

```
import sqlalchemy
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import random
import string
from odo import odo, resource, discover, dshape
import time

start_time = time.time()

HOST = 'localhost'
USER = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'password'
PORT = 5432
DATABASE = 'csv_database'
CSV_DB_TABLE = 'csv_table'
CSV_FILE = "csv/sample.csv"   

def connect(user, password, db, host='localhost', port=5432):
    url = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'
    url = url.format(user, password, host, port, db)
    con = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')
    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=con, reflect=True)
    return con, meta

def load_data_odo(table_name, filename, origin=CSV_FILE):
    if origin == CSV_FILE:
        ds = dshape(
            "var * {id: int64,title1: int64,title2: int64,title3: int64,title4: float64,title5: datetime,title6: string,title7: string,title8: string,title9: string,title10: string,title11: string,title12: datetime,title13: string,title14: string}")   


def random_string():
    digits = "".join([random.choice(string.digits + string.ascii_letters) for i in range(10)])
    return digits    

def new_file_gen(filename, origin=None, start_index=0, column_name=None):
    new_file_name = '{}.csv'.format(random_string())
    # os.chmod(new_file_name, 0777)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        # print (df)    
    if origin == CSV_FILE:
        df['Customer No'] = df['Customer No'].astype(str).str.slice(0, 10)
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])            

    total_length = len(df.index)
    if column_name:
        column_name = column_name
    else:
        column_name = start_index + 1
    new_column = pd.DataFrame({column_name: range(start_index + 1, start_index + total_length + 1)})
    new_column = new_column.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    new_column.drop(new_column.index[0])
    new_column.to_csv(new_file_name, index=False)
    return {'file': new_file_name, 'shape': df.shape}    

def create_file_with_header(filename):
    new_file_name = '{}.csv'.format(random_string())
    names = "title1,title2,title3,title4,title5,title6,title7,title8,title9,title10,title11,title12,title13,title14".split(",")

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
    df.columns = names
    df.to_csv(new_file_name, index=False, header=True)
    return new_file_name

def get_last_id(table_name, columnname="id"):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=DATABASE, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, host=HOST, port=PORT)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "SELECT {} from {} order by {} desc limit 1;".format(columnname, table_name, columnname)
    # print query

    cursor.execute(query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    if records and len(records[0]) > 0:
        return records[0][0]
    else:
        return 0    

def read_data(table_name):
    con, meta = connect(USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE)
    test1 = meta.tables[table_name]
    for row in con.execute(test1.select()):
        print row
    print con    

def print_data(table_name):
    print "#" * 30, "Data", "#" * 30
    read_data(table_name) 

def csv_file_import():
    start_time = time.time()
    filename = CSV_FILE
    table_name = CSV_DB_TABLE
    index = get_last_id(table_name, columnname="id")
    panda = new_file_gen(filename=filename, origin=filename, start_index=index, column_name="id")
    load_data_odo(table_name, filename=panda['file'], origin=CSV_FILE)
    os.remove(panda['file'])
    return "File {} Shape {} Done in :--- {} seconds ---".format(filename, panda['shape'], time.time() - start_time)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print (csv_file_import())
```

Once i run the script a temporary file is created but process fails during file reading, i am an intermediate python developer not a pro. Any one having an idea please?